# How to add attribute and remove from an element in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

`<input name="name" type="text" ng-model="numbers" mandatory>`

How to remove and add class of mandatory dinamically in Angular JS?

Note : "mandatory" is custom class which is implemented by me.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to add or remove class bu your own when you're populating with angular. Angular will do it for you. see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm

Comment: You are not looking for `required`, right?

Comment: Are you looking to remove and add a Class or an Attribute?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by *mandatory*. But to apply class based on condition we do

```
<input name="name" type="text" ng-model="numbers" mandatory ng-class="{className: expression}">
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-class is option in Angularjs to add class dynamically

follow the doc for more info

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change the class on button click

```
    <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="numbers" mandatory ng-class="class">
 <button ng-click="changeClass()">Change Class</button>
```

Now Add or remove class in controller

```
app.controller("con",function($scope){

        $scope.class = "class1";

        $scope.changeClass = function(){
          if ($scope.class === "class1")
            $scope.class = "class2";
          else
            $scope.class = "class1";
        };
      });
```